# Displaying image from uri path

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I have an `URI` path and I want to display the image in an `ImageView`.

So far I've done this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("/external/images/media/20066");
imageView.setImageURI(null);
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

But didn't work. I'm new in android. Can someone help me?

Comment: Where did you get that path from?

Comment: your image is stored at sdcard or in assert folder?

Comment: Try to use path Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/media/20066"

Comment: the path is from another activity
list.get(listPosition).getImageURI().getPath()

i used it like above just for test. 

i think the image is stored at sdcard

Comment: @nnesterov i have tried in this form: 
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/images/media/20066");

but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/20066")` and try removing `imageView.setImageURI(null)`